# Is there a shortened method to loop through conditions in IF in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, conditional-statements

So I am making a program that needs to check if a file is of Video / Audio format.
To do this I have this code (Song is a `System.IO.FileInfo`):

```
If Song.Extension.ToUpper = ".MP4" Or Song.Extension = ".AVI" Or Song.Extension = ".MP3" Or Song.Extension = ".AA" Or Song.Extension = ".M4A" Or Song.Extension = ".AIFF" Or Song.Extension = ".WAV" Or Song.Extension = ".M4V" Or Song.Extension = ".AAC" Or Song.Extension = ".VOB" Then
```

The problem is that this only checks the first 2 conditions.
Do I need to split this into separate `If`s or is there some way to test all the conditions in one line?

Comment: How do you know it only checks the first two conditions? You forgot `.ToUpper` on the rest of them, mind.

Comment: @Ryan Thank You! I added '.ToUpper' and it worked! BTW, I thought it only does the first two because of the 'or' description.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make a set with all the extensions in it:

```
Dim extensions As New HashSet(Of String) From {
    ".mp4", ".avi", ".mp3", ".aa", ".m4a", ".aiff", ".wav",
    ".m4v", ".aac", ".vob"
}
```

and check if a value is in it with `Contains`:

```
If extensions.Contains(Song.Extension.ToLower()) Then
    ⋮
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that it would be easier to use a select case construct with just one case:

```
    Select Case Song.Extension.ToLower
        Case ".mp4", ".avi", ".mp3", ".aa", ".m4a", ".aiff", ".wav", ".m4v", ".aac", ".vob"
            'Do something
    End Select
```

Comment: Case makes no sense if there is only ONE condition to be checked.

Comment: Why does it make no sense?

Comment: You're only checking one condition in `Select Case` statement.

Comment: Actually it's checking 10 conditions with one result. But you haven't stated why you think it makes no sense. There's no rule that says a case structure needs more than one case statement.